# Neither @AppStorage no UserDefaults works in SwiftUI init/didSet code

Tags: swift, swiftui

This code doesn't work: AppStorage is not actually save the data.

```
struct DayInfoView: View {

    @State private var selectedDate: Date
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @AppStorage("checkmarkVisible") private var checkmarkVisibleData: Data = Data()
    @State private var checkmarkVisible: Set<Date> = [] {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(checkmarkVisible) {
                checkmarkVisibleData = encoded
            }
            print(checkmarkVisible)
        }
    }
var body: someView {
//// some code
Button(action: {
                        checkmarkVisible.insert(selectedDate)
                    }) {
                        Text("Button 2")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
}
}
```

Same incorrect behaviour is for directly userdefaults methods calls.

```
class UserDefaultsService {
    static let shared = UserDefaultsService()

    func save<T: Codable>(_ value: T, forKey key: String) {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: key)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }

    func load<T: Codable>(forKey key: String, defaultValue: T) -> T {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key),
           let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) {
            return value
        }
        return defaultValue
    }
}

struct DayInfoView: View {
    @State private var selectedDate: Date
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    private let userDefaultsService = UserDefaultsService.shared

    @State private var checkmarkVisible: Set<Date> = [] {
        didSet {
            userDefaultsService.save(checkmarkVisible, forKey: "checkmarkVisible")
            print(checkmarkVisible)
        }
    }

    init(selectedDate: Date) {
        _selectedDate = State(initialValue: selectedDate)
        let storedCheckmarkVisible: Set<Date> = userDefaultsService.load(forKey: "checkmarkVisible", defaultValue: Set<Date>())
        _checkmarkVisible = State(initialValue: storedCheckmarkVisible)
    }
```

Why? How to resolve such issue?

[synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize) doesn't work too.

**NOTE**

The behaviour is unpredictable . From time to time it saves or not.

Comment: How are you testing this? I have seen in UIKit (but I doubt that matters) that killing the app in Xcode very soon after saving to user defaults will lose the save. I think there is a delay between setting a value and it really being persisted to user defaults. I don’t think synchronise has done anything for years. To be sure that user default changes are persisted I find going back to the home screen, waiting a few seconds then killing the app will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution - use file. But I don't understand, how to use appstorage/userdefaults

```
final class UserDefaultsService {
    static let shared = UserDefaultsService()

    private let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    func save<T: Codable>(_ value: T, forKey key: String) {
        let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(key)
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value) {
            do {
                try encoded.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
            } catch {
                print("Error saving data to disk: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func load<T: Codable>(forKey key: String, defaultValue: T) -> T {
        let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(key)
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL),
           let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) {
            return value
        }
        return defaultValue
    }
}
```